# How can I animate individual links in a navbar?

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a website and I have a navbar using the **HTML5** *nav* tags:

```
<nav class="contact">
                <a   href="#"><img src="images/twitter_icon.png"></a>
                <a   href="#"><img src="images/insta_icon.png"></a>
                <a   href="#"><img src="images/git_icon.png"></a>
                <a   href="#"><img src="images/youtube_icon.png"></a>
                <a   href="#"><img src="images/email_icon.png"></a>
                <a   href="#"><img src="images/stack_icon.png"></a>
</nav>
```

This is inside a main page *div*

Now I want to animate these individual pictures when the user hovers over them. I came up with the following, but it is animating the entire navbar:

```
nav {
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 30px;
}
nav a img {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
}
nav a:hover img {
animation-name: move;
animation-duration: 0.2s;
}
@keyframes move{
from{margin-top: 0%;}
to{margin-top: 10%;}
}
nav a {
display: inline-block;
margin: 12px 0px 10px 20px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm a bit rusty with these languages since I haven't used them in a while

Comment: instead of animating on margin-top, animate on transform: translateY(10%) -- note this won't work on webkit, you need a solid value i.e. 10px.  You might also have to fiddle with the position.  Adjusting the margin might have inadvertently moved your nav bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the height of the `nav` changes when you hover an anchor (see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s11g4Ldy/)). You also place them as inline-blocks... therefor they are vertical aligned at the bottom.

Add a `vertical-align: top` to the anchors, and it works:

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
nav a img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
nav a:hover img {
    animation-name: move;
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
}
@keyframes move {
    from {
        margin-top: 0%;
    }
    to {
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
}
nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 12px 0px 10px 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<nav class="contact">
    <a   href="#"><img src="images/twitter_icon.png"/></a>
    <a   href="#"><img src="images/insta_icon.png"/></a>
    <a   href="#"><img src="images/git_icon.png"/></a>
    <a   href="#"><img src="images/youtube_icon.png"/></a>
    <a   href="#"><img src="images/email_icon.png"/></a>
    <a   href="#"><img src="images/stack_icon.png"/></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes, why shouldn't it be? Of course are there other ways, but if this works for you...

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, I think you would be better off using translateY in lieu of margin-top.  Take for example the broken demo, simply swapping to translateY resolves your issue.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/f4p5jxrx/